# Why is mounting the /var/hyperledger/production to the host volume causing an error?

Tags: docker, hyperledger

I tried mounting the /var/hyperledger/production folder to the host (I'm using Windows 7 and running Docker through Docker ToolBox) so that the enrollment certificates will be retained when my hyperledger peer docker container exits.

Here is the command I used:

```
docker run   --name c_vp0   --rm -it  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  -v /c/Users/hyperledger/production:/var/hyperledger/production -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock   -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0   -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true   -e CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_CONSENSUS_PLUGIN=noop   -e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=ERROR   -e CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true   -e CORE_SECURITY_PRIVACY=true   -e CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=172.17.0.50:7054   -e CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=172.17.0.50:7054   -e CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=172.17.0.50:7054   -e CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0   -e CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT   hyperledger/fabric-peer  peer node start
```

However, I encounter the following error:

```
panic: Error opening DB: IO error: directory: Invalid argument
```

I modified the command "peer node start" to "/bin/bash" so that I can inspect the mounted directory.  I noticed that the ownership/group of /var/hyperledger/production (and its subdirectories and files) is 1000:staff instead of root:root.

I'm not sure if this is causing the problem but I tried using the chown command to change the ownership/group to root:root but it does not work.

Comment: did you try running the container is privileged mode (--privileged)? /var/run is probably owned by root on the host, so the container might have issues accessing it without being privileged.

Comment: Hi @Ehud.  I included --privileged but it is still causing the panic error.

Comment: can you share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be incompatibilities between leveldb and the vboxfs used by VirtualBox ([see example here](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/794)). I'm not sure who is at fault, but search results show success  when using leveldb on volumes mounted without vboxfs.

Upgrade from Docker Toolbox, which uses VirtualBox, to [Docker for Windows](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows), which used Window's built in Hyper-V virtualization.

If you can't run Docker for Windows (e.g. you will need to upgrade your Windows 7 to at least Windows 10, then attempt to mount `/var/hyperledger/production` to your host folder via some other method such as NFS.